# How to create an Idempotent Operation for a Banking Application that has a withdrawAmount Method

Tags: java, rest, idempotent

We have a Banking Application that has a Withdraw REST API, can someone tell me how to make this method as an Idempotent operation?

Answer (score 2):

You've already studied what an idempotent operation is. In theory - the operation should return the same response for the same request. It is a way how to enable reliable delivery with non-transactional services.

It may happend that the same call is received multiple times, but the amount must be withdrawn from the account only once.

Practically - having multiple calls with the same parameters (transaction details) should return the same response (but do not do anything). The easiest way is having a unique transaction identifer if the transaction has already happend, the service should just return the same response as the first call (without really withdrawing the banking account).